# Swift compiling of multiple switch case fallthroughs and the same named associated value is unstable and often crashes

Tags: swift

Swift compiler often crashes with multiple (>=2) switch case fallthroughs and the same named associated value. The following code doesn't compile for Swift version 4.2:

```
enum Foo {
    case a(count: Int)
    case b(count: Int)
    case c(count: Int)
    case d
}

func bar(v: Foo) {
    switch v {
    case .a(let count): fallthrough
    case .b(let count): fallthrough
    case .c(let count):
        print(count)
    case .d: break
    }
}

bar(v: .a(count: 4))
```

Bug report submitted at: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-9729

Comment: It haven't crashed for me, you had `case .d` outside of `switch` though.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if Swift permits `fallthrough` with value-binding.

But this surely works:

```
func bar(v: Foo) {
    switch v {
    case .a(let count),
         .b(let count),
         .c(let count):
        print(count)
    case .d: break
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, this does work, thanks. But still, 'fallthroughs' way causes the compiler to be unstable and occasionally/often crash.

Comment: @rikki, `fallthrough` usage can be omitted in absolute majority of cases, there's almost always a better way to do it without using `fallthrough`.

Comment: ok, thanks, but still it's a bug which caused me to spend a couple of hours to isolate the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Workaround:

```
enum Foo {
    case a(count: Int)
    case b(count: Int)
    case c(count: Int)
    case d

    var count: Int {
        if case .a(let count) = self {
            return count
        } else if case .b(let count) = self {
            return count
        } else if case .c(let count) = self {
            return count
        } else {
            fatalError()
        }
    }
}

func bar(v: Foo) {
    switch v {
    case .a: fallthrough
    case .b: fallthrough
    case .c:
        print(v.count)
    case .d: break
    }
}

bar(v: .a(count: 4))
```

Comment: Eh, why don't you just use `if case` instead of `switch` in `bar` function then?

Comment: this is an excerpt from a large source file for a demonstrating purpose. In my project the structure with switch is more appropriate. Thanks